# line-endings detection

Tags: perl

I would like to detect which is the line-endings type of a file. I wrote this function:

```
 open my $fh, '<afile.txt';
 seteol($fh);
```

Here the eol detection subroutine:

```
 sub seteol {
    my $fh = shift;
    my $byte;
    my $i = 0;
    while (sysread($fh, $byte, 1)) {    
        if($byte eq "\n") {
            $/ = "\n";                
            return 0;
        }
        elsif($byte eq "\r") {
            sysread($fh, $byte, 1);
            if($byte eq "\n") {
                $/ = "\r\n";
                return 0;
            } else {
                $/ = "\r";
                return 0;
            }
        }
        last if $i++ > 65535;
    }
    return -1;
    seek($fh,0,0);     
}
```

I am wondering if I can do a better job with only core-modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It reads file by 4096 chars in hope to find EOL,

```
local $/ = seteol($fh) // $/;

sub seteol {
    my $fh = shift;

    local $/ = \4096;
    my $line = "";

    while (my $b = <$fh>) {        
      $line .= $b;
      last if $line =~ /(\R)/;
    }
    seek($fh,0,0);
    return $1 if $1;

    warn "Unknown EOL";
    return;
}
```

Comment: @coin check update

Comment: Why did you chose 4096?

Comment: @coin for no particular reason, it is 4kb in a hope that it would be enough to find EOL with first read.